# Тире вместо пропущенного члена предложения

Tags: пунктуация, тире

*Геологу, вышедшему из леса, посёлок показался большим городом: глаза его за три месяца отвыкли от ярких огней, а ноги (–) от асфальта и булыжника.*

Почему в данном предложении не ставится тире после "ноги"? Тут же явно пропущено сказуемое "отвыкли".

Comment: А почему Вы решили, что не ставится? В книге Анатолия Алексина, которую можно найти  в сети, тире в этом предложении стоит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Постановка тире очень часто зависит от "ритма" предложения, от наличия или отсутствия пауз, задуманных автором текста.

> 5. Тире ставится в неполном предложении, составляющем часть сложного предложения, когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое) восстанавливается из предыдущей части фразы и в месте пропуска делается пауза: ...*Мир освещается солнцем, а человек — знанием* (Посл.)...
>    При отсутствии паузы в месте пропуска члена предложения тире не ставится: *Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку* (Ч.)...

Источник: [**Тире в неполном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93) (Розенталь).

Answer (score 1):

…………………………… Вместо комментария:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]